# Prove that a subset is normal

Tags: matrices

Let $H$ be the subset of $GL(2, \mathbb R)$ consisting of all matrices of the form

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
x & 0\\
0 & x\\
    \end{array}
\right] $$

where $x \neq 0$

Prove that H is normal.

**UPDATE**

So if I show $\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right]$

commutes with everything in $ GL(2, \mathbb R)$, I can do something like $$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right]^{-1}$$  $$= \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right]^{-1}$$
$$ = \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right] \in H$$

Yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect, you want to show that for any $$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right] \in GL(2, \mathbb R)$$
and $$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right] \in H$$
then $$\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right]\left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}
\right]^{-1}\in H$$

To begin, I'd actually try to prove the general fact that any subgroup whose elements commute with all other elements of the group, is normal.

Comment: Any direction on how to prove that$ \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
h & 0\\
0 & h\\
    \end{array}
\right] $ commutes with everything in $GL(2, \mathbb R)$?

Comment: @Harry The most simplistic proof is just trying both products with arbitrary $a,b,c,d,h$ and seeing that they're equal. A more involved fact though (just FYI) is that if an element of $GL(2,\Bbb R)$ commutes with every element, it has to be in $H$. We then call $H$ the [center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_%28group_theory%29) of $GL(2,\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Ah I see, I updated my original post, did I do this correctly? Thanks for the help

Comment: @Harry Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed on the wrong track. Sounds like you have shown $H$ to be a subgroup. As for proving $H$ is a normal subgroup, we pick any arbitrary element $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right] \in \text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ and prove that $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x & 0\\
0 & x\\
    \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right]^{-1} \in H$. It will probably be helpful to recall $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right]^{-1} = \frac{1}{ad-bc}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
d & -b\\
-c & a\\
    \end{array}\right]$$ So simply (although a bit tiresome) calculate by hand that the product $$\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x & 0\\
0 & x\\
    \end{array}\right]\left(\frac{1}{ad-bc}\left[\begin{array}{cc}
d & -b\\
-c & a\\
    \end{array}\right]\right)$$ and show it will equal some matrix of the form $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
z & 0\\
0 & z\\
    \end{array}\right]$ with $z \neq 0 $. This will complete the proof.

Comment: Thanks, I actually have proven that is was a subgroup, I should have put this in the original post. I'm still stuck on how to prove that $\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
x & 0\\
0 & x\\
    \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}\right]^{-1} \in H$

Comment: @Harry The idea outlined in your newest edit will also work. Although I would hold off on using the center if you have not yet covered it in class

Comment: I am accepting another poster's answer simply because they helped me solve the problem first, but your answer was also beneficial. I will upvote it, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

**Definition**

A ***subgroup*** $H$ of $G$ is normal if for each $g \in G$ and $h \in H$ $ ghg^{-1} \in H$.

So you are off to a bad start to begin with. First you  need to show that $H$ is in fact a subgroup. It is not difficult to show closure and the existence of the inverse for each element. Then you need to show that, $$ \left({  \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}} \right) \left({  \begin{array}{cc}
x & 0\\
0 & x\\
    \end{array}} \right) \left({  \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}} \right)^{-1} \in H $$

$$ $$

Comment: Did you mean that $$ \left({  \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}} \right) \left({  \begin{array}{cc}
x & 0\\
0 & x\\
    \end{array}} \right) \left({  \begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d\\
    \end{array}} \right)^{-1} \in H $$ ?

Comment: @Harry, Yes. Sorry.